# Theory of promonads

Tags: category-theory, monoidal-categories, monads

I'm led to define a *promonad* in $\bf D$ as a monoid in the category of endo-profunctors of a category $\bf D$, where the product of two profunctors is their composition as profunctors:
$$
F\odot G := \int^D F(-,D)\times G(D,-)
$$
Is this theory developed in a general fashion in any book/article?

In the case $\bf D$ is small discrete, promonads in $\bf D$ correspond to small categories having $\bf D$ as set of objects, which I find quite astounding: can this result be generalized to the case where $\bf D$ is any small category, leading to a notion of "thick" category? What's the intuition behind this structure?

And how can I recognize in $\text{Pro-Mnd}(\bf D)$ various categories I can obtain from the set $\bf D$ (the discrete one should correspond to a "trivial" promonad, the maximally connected groupoid to another promonad which I'm not able to characterize)?

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not convinced your characterisation is correct. A promonad on a small category $\mathbb{D}$ should correspond to a monad on $[\mathbb{D}^\textrm{op}, \textbf{Set}]$ whose underlying endofunctor preserves all colimits.

Comment: Maybe in the case D is discrete your characterization boils down to mine. But don't take too seriously my comment, I'm in a hurry now... Thank you for your answer!

Comment: There are lots of examples of this sort of thing; a monad in any compact closed bicategory gives a category-like thing.  For example, a monad in (sets, relations, implications) gives a preorder; a monad in (objects of C, spans in C, maps of spans) gives a category internal to C; a monad in Mat(R) gives an R-enriched category; and a symmetric monoidal monad in (small categories, profunctors, natural transformations) gives a Freyd category.  Functional programmers follow Hughes in calling Freyd categories "Arrows".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A promonad 'in' category $\bf D$ is the categorical correspondent of an *algebra* over a ring $R$.

I prefer to look at profunctors $\ F:{\bf A}^{op}\times{\bf B}\to\bf{Set}\ $ as their *collages*: considering the elements of each $F(A,B)$ as 'outer arrows' (*heteromorphisms*) from $A$ to $B$, thus giving a bigger category which contains (disjointly) $\bf A$ and $\bf B$ and these heteromorphisms.

The heteromorphisms of the composition $F\odot G$ are just the consecutive pairs of heteromorphisms (quotienting out by $\langle f\beta,g\rangle\,\sim\,\langle f,\beta g\rangle$ for $\beta$ in the middle category, as a kind of *tensor product*).

Then, an endoprofunctor $F:{\bf D}\not\to {\bf D}$ contains the same objects as $\bf D$ (each one twice), and possibly heteromorphisms among them. A monoid structure adds an associative *composition* operation $F\odot F\to F$, and an 'insertion' $\hom_{\bf D}\to F$, representing all original $\bf D$-arrows as actual heteromorphisms in $F$ (note that this is not required to be injective). This yields to a category $\bf F$ on objects of $\bf D$ with the heteromorphisms of $F$ as arrows, equipped with the 'insertion' functor ${\bf D}\to{\bf F}$.

So, in this view, a promonad over $\bf D$ is just another category $\bf F$ on the same object class equipped with a functor $U:\bf D\to\bf F$, which is identical on the objects:

If such is given, form the profunctor $F$ so that $F(A,B):={\bf F}(A,B)$, for morphisms $\gamma:A'\to A,\ \ \delta:B\to B'$, define
$$\ F(\gamma,\delta):= f\mapsto U\delta\circ f\circ U\gamma\,,$$
the monoid structure is coming from the composition in $\bf F$, plus $U$ as the unit.

Comment: This is lovely! Is there a standard reference for the translations between promonads and categories on the same object class?

Comment: I'm not aware of any. But this is analogous to the case when an algebra over a ring $R$ might be defined simply as a ring homomorphism $R\to A$..

Answer (score 7):

I prefer to think of profunctors $\mathbb{A} \to \mathbb{B}$ (which for me means a functor $\mathbb{A} \to [\mathbb{B}^{\textrm{op}}, \textbf{Set}]$) as secretly being colimit-preserving functors $[\mathbb{A}^\textrm{op}, \textbf{Set}] \to [\mathbb{B}^\textrm{op}, \textbf{Set}]$. Indeed, the presheaf topos $[\mathbb{A}^\textrm{op}, \textbf{Set}]$ is characterised by the following universal property:

- For every cocomplete category $\mathcal{E}$, the functor $\textbf{Cocont}([\mathbb{A}^\textrm{op}, \textbf{Set}], \mathcal{E}) \to [\mathbb{A}, \mathcal{E}]$ sending a colimit-preserving functor $F : [\mathbb{A}^\textrm{op}, \textbf{Set}] \to \mathcal{E}$ to the composite $F Y : \mathbb{A} \to \mathcal{E}$, where $Y : \mathbb{A} \to [\mathbb{A}^\textrm{op}, \textbf{Set}]$ is the Yoneda embedding, is fully faithful and surjective on objects.

In particular, $[\mathbb{B}^\textrm{op}, \textbf{Set}]$ is a cocomplete category, so the category of functors $\mathbb{A} \to [\mathbb{B}^\textrm{op}, \textbf{Set}]$ is pseudonaturally equivalent to the category of colimit-preserving functors $[\mathbb{A}^\textrm{op}, \textbf{Set}] \to [\mathbb{B}^\textrm{op}, \textbf{Set}]$, and one can check that this makes the bicategory of small categories and profunctors 3-equivalent to the 2-category of presheaf toposes and colimit-preserving functors. (One may think of the bicategory of profunctors as being a bicategorical analogue of the Kleisli category for the pseudomonad that sends a small category to its free cocompletion... but such a pseudomonad cannot be defined on the 2-category of small categories, so this is not literally true.)

Thus, a monad on $\mathbb{A}$ in the bicategory of profunctors is the same thing as a monad on $[\mathbb{A}^\textrm{op}, \textbf{Set}]$ whose underlying endofunctor preserves colimits. It is certainly true that every category $\mathbb{B}$ that admits an identity-on-objects functor $\mathbb{A} \to \mathbb{B}$ induces such a monad: indeed, by precomposition, we get a conservative functor $[\mathbb{B}^\textrm{op}, \textbf{Set}] \to [\mathbb{A}^\textrm{op}, \textbf{Set}]$ with a left and right adjoint, and thus by Beck's monadicity theorem, $[\mathbb{B}^\textrm{op}, \textbf{Set}]$ is monadic over $[\mathbb{A}^\textrm{op}, \textbf{Set}]$.

On the other hand, suppose we have a monad $\mathsf{T}$ on $[\mathbb{A}^\textrm{op}, \textbf{Set}]$ whose underlying endofunctor preserves colimits. Let $\mathcal{B}$ be the category of $\mathsf{T}$-algebras. By standard nonsense, the forgetful functor $U : \mathcal{B} \to [\mathbb{A}^\textrm{op}, \textbf{Set}]$ is conservative, has a left adjoint $F : [\mathbb{A}^\textrm{op}, \textbf{Set}]$, and creates both limits and colimits. Using Weber's nerve theorem, it follows that the full subcategory $\mathbb{B}$ of $\mathcal{B}$ spanned by the $\mathsf{T}$-algebras of the form $F Y A$ for $A$ an object in $\mathbb{A}$ has the property that the restricted Yoneda embedding $\mathcal{B} \to [\mathbb{B}^\textrm{op}, \textbf{Set}]$ is fully faithful and preserves all colimits. But the universal property of $[\mathbb{B}^\textrm{op}, \textbf{Set}]$ implies that this is an equivalence of categories, so in fact every monad whose underlying endofunctor preserves colimits must be of this form.

Answer (score 5):

Before we start some general facts about cocomplete monoidal closed category:

- in any category of this kind $\mathcal V$ we can build up the bicategory of monoid, bimodules and bimodules morphisms;
- fixed any monoid $M$ in this bicategory we can consider the monoidal category of $M,M$-bimodules;
- in such monoidal category a monoid is just a monoid $N$ in $\mathcal V$ with a monoid morphism $M \to N$.

This last fact is the generalization of the well know fact about  $R$-algebras, i.e. that every $R$-algebra can be viewed as an $R,R$-bimodule with a $R$-linear associative and unital multiplication or as a ring with a ring homomorphism from $R$ (we remind that rings are monoid in the cocomplete closed monoidal category $\mathbf {Ab})$.

Now let's do some work!

[John Baez told](http://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2008/08/bimodules_versus_spans.html) that we can recover the bicategory of sets, spans between set and span morphisms as the bicategory of monoids, bimodules and bimodules morphisms on $\mathbf {Set}^\text{op}$.

A monad in such bicategory is nothing more than a category (as you stated in the question) and a bimodule is just a profunctor.

So the bicategory of categories, profunctors and natural transformation between those is nothing but the bicategory of monoids, bimodules and bimodules morphisms in $\mathbf {Set}^\text{op}$.

Ok now back to your question: what is a monad in such bicategory? Well for start a monad is a monoid in one of the monoidal category of $C,C$-bimodules (a.k.a. profunctors).

A monad should just be a $C,C$-bimodule for some category/monoid $C$, with a $C$-linear monoidal structure.

From what we have said above this is data are equivalent to a monoid $N$ in the monoidal category of spans in $\mathcal{O}(C)$ (so $N$ is just a category) with a monoid morphism (i.e. a functor) from the category $C$ to $N$.

Hope this helps.